# Unable to append list in flutter in this model class

Tags: android, flutter

```
class FeatureClass {
 String head;
 int id;
 bool isChecked;
 FeatureClass(this.isChecked, this.head, this.id);
 List<FeatureClass> featureClassesList = List <FeatureClass>();
 featureClassesList.add(FeatureClass { FeatureID = 1, FeatureTitle = "F1", IsChecked = false });
 featureClassesList.add(new FeatureClass { FeatureID = 1, FeatureTitle = "F1", IsChecked = false });
 featureClassesList.add(new FeatureClass { FeatureID = 2, FeatureTitle = "F2", IsChecked = false });
}
```

It's not letting me append these values into my list. The error I'm receiving is "Constructors must match enclosing class name". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many mistakes in your code!

The first one is that you can't write instructions directly inside a class, it must be in a method or in the constructor (which is where you should do it in your case).

The second mistake you made is that you call the constructor of a class with () not {}!

A correct version of your code would be:

```
class FeatureClass {
  String head;
  int id;
  bool isChecked;

  FeatureClass(this.isChecked, this.head, this.id) {
    featureClassesList.add(FeatureClass(false, "F1", 1));
    featureClassesList.add(FeatureClass(false, "F2", 1));
    featureClassesList.add(FeatureClass(false, "F3", 1));
  }

  List<FeatureClass> featureClassesList = List<FeatureClass>();
}
```